# Entity Framework - Count distinct books pr. tag using navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table "Book" with a many-to-many relationship to "Tag" and need a distinct Book-count pr. Tag. In SQL, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT t.NAME,
count(DISTINCT b.BookId)
FROM _Tag t
JOIN Book.BookTag bt
ON t.Id = bt.TagId
JOIN Books b
ON b.BookId = bt.BookId
GROUP BY t.NAME
ORDER BY count(DISTINCT b.BookId) DESC;
```

I have fetched the tags and included the Books navigation-property and from this I should be able to get distinct BookId's pr. tagname. I want to get the result in a tuple.

So far I have tried the following:

```
var tagTuples = from tag in tags
join book in tags.Select(t => t.Books) on tag.Books equals book
group new {tag, book} by tag.Name
into g
select new Tuple<string, string, int>("tags", g.Key, g.Select(x => x.book).Count());
```

...and...

```
var tagTuples = tags.GroupBy(t => t.Name)
.Select(t2 => new Tuple<string, string, int>("tags", t2.Key, t2.Sum(t4 => t4.Books
.Select(b => b.BookId).Distinct().Count())))
.Where(t3 => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t3.Item2)).Take(15);
```

...and my latest version:

```
var tagTuples =
tags.Select(t => new {t.Name, BookId = t.Books.Select(b => b.BookId)})
.GroupBy(tb => tb.Name)
.Select(tb2 => new Tuple<string, string, int>("tags", tb2.Key, tb2.Sum(tb3 => tb3.BookId.Distinct().Count())));
```

Nevermind the small differences in the query's - I'm only interested in a solution to the problem described above.

Frustration! It takes me 2 minutes to write an SQL query that does this and I'm pretty sure there's a simple answer, but I lack EF routine.

Thankyou for your time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(var ctx = new EntitiesContext())
{
                                  // GROUP By name
    var bookCountByTag = ctx.Tags.GroupBy(t => t.Name)
                            .Select(t2 => new { 
                                // SELECT the key (tag name)
                                t2.Key, 

                                // "GroupBy" has many result, so use SelectMany
                                Count = t2.SelectMany(t3 => t3.book)
                                          .Distinct()
                                          .Count()})
                            .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! When trying out your answer, I found out that I forgot to filter on a category before counting the books, which bloated my bookcount. One of my own examples actually worked, but yours is simpler. Thankyou for your time. :)

Comment: The category filtering was left out for simplicity. ;)